# How to speedup electing the primary in mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have three shards. Each shard has two mongod instances as data servers.
Some times it takes too long to elect one primary from two secondaries in one shard.
How can I speed up the election process? Are there examples for me to follow to do some extra configuration?

Thanks

Comment: How long is too long? How long do your elections take? What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: when the primary is shutdown, it takes long time to elect the new primary from the remaining two secondary

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the setting you are looking for is [electionTimeoutMillis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.settings.electionTimeoutMillis):

> New in version 3.2.
>
> Optional.
>
> Type: int
>
> Default: 10000 (10 seconds)
>
> The time limit in milliseconds for detecting when a replica set’s
>   primary is unreachable:
>
> Higher values result in slower failovers but decreased sensitivity to
>   primary node or network slowness or spottiness. Lower values result in
>   faster failover, but increased sensitivity to primary node or network
>   slowness or spottiness. The setting only applies when using
>   protocolVersion: 1.

For your particular situation, where you are manually shutting down the current primary, there is a relevant change in 4.0.2:

> If the parameter enableElectionHandoff is true (default), when a
>   primary steps down from rs.stepDown() (or the replSetStepDown command
>   without the force: true), the stepped-down primary nominates an
>   eligible secondary to call an election immediately. Otherwise,
>   secondaries can wait up to settings.electionTimeoutMillis before
>   calling an election. The stepped down primary does not wait for the
>   effects of the handoff. For more information, see
>   enableElectionHandoff.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.settings.electionTimeoutMillis) for up to date information and details on how to configure your replica set. You may also want to check out the article for [replica set elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) which gives a good overview of how elections work.